# How to use rayleigh_distribution<> from boost library in c++?

Tags: c++, random, distribution

I'm trying to generate random number using Rayleigh distribution.
I have implemented this using the c++ the library below:

```
#include <boost/math/distributions/rayleigh.hpp>

boost::math::rayleigh_distribution<> rayleigh();
```

I don't know how to use this library to return number related to `sigma`.

Comment: [boost::math::rayleigh_distribution<>](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/dist/dist_ref/dists/rayleigh.html) is a class (template). I assume you want an instance of this class (template instance with default settings). In this case: `boost::math::rayleigh_distribution<> rayleigh();` is wrong. The last pair of parentheses makes this a _function declaration_. To make this a _default constructed class instance_, please, delete the parentheses or replace them by `{}`.

Comment: This is a common pitfall of C++ which happens most C++ programmers unexpectedly at least once in their career... ;-)

Comment: Btw. I don't know anything about this class template or distributions in general but the above linked doc. mentions under `// Accessors:` `RealType sigma() const;`.

Comment: Finally, I managed to find the [Rayleigh Distribution](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/dist_ref/dists/rayleigh.html) in the most recent version. (The above link is rather a bit aged but the offered link to current version is somehow broken.)

Comment: Thank you very much @Scheff Yes, I saw this site. My problem is I need to return random number and have possibility to change the sigma. I don't really know how to do it.

`boost::math::rayleigh_distribution<> rayleigh;
rayleigh.sigma(); ` (i cant put any argument into this method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sigma is passed in the constructor, so do it like this:

```
const double sigma = 5.;
boost::math::rayleigh_distribution<> rayleigh(sigma);
```

The method sigma() merely returns a copy of the set sigma, so you cannot use that.

What Scheff was referring to is that it would also work (given you want sigma to be 1.) if you do that

```
boost::math::rayleigh_distribution<> rayleigh{};
```

as this has no ambiguity with a function declaration, but is setting sigma to 1.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thank you! Could you advice me if i can make this distribution dependent on the seed? And in which way return result of this function?

Comment: Do you have some code I can look at? Don't really know what you mean :(

Comment: `void room::measurement_error_raylegh_distribution()
{
 const double sigma = 5.;
 boost::math::rayleigh_distribution<double> rayleigh(sigma);
}`
This is function which should return number

Comment: ;) Well, that is basically the same thing wrapped in a function, but I cannot get any more information out

Comment: For example this is code for normal distribution and I need to do the same with Rayleigh:
`void room::measurement_error_normal_distribution()
{
 std::normal_distribution<double> distribution(5.0, 2.0);
 double seed = return_error_generator()->Rand_v3();
 std::default_random_engine e(seed);
 error_1_st = distribution(e);
}`

Comment: Okay, so you want to look into boost::random. I think this distribution class is not what you want, as far as I know.